# fail to add text on the button in pygame

Tags: python, button, pygame

I want to add a text on my button, and I followed a tutorial online and write the code as instructed, however, the text still not display on the button successfully, here is my code:

```
    ButtonText = pygame.font.SysFont("freesansbold.ttf", 10)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects("Mute", ButtonText)
    textRect.center = ((20+(50/2)), (20+(20/2)))
    background.blit(textSurf, textRect)
```

And I defined text_objects in the top:

```
def text_objects(text, font):
    black = (0,0,0)
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()
```

And instead of showing the text "Mute", it showed a mass of black there. Can anyone help me fix this? Thank you in advance. [image]

Comment: Hi Wendy, could you please upload full code?

Comment: @SachinPatel Users should extremely rarely upload their full code. A question should contain a [mcve]. If users paste in their full code it'll make the question too specific to be valuable for others, and it'll usually contain too much code, which makes it harder to read and reason about.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are not specifying a background for the font be drawn on so it is creating a blank one for you. That is to say a black one. You might want to amend your code to this:

```
def text_objects(text, font):
    black = (0,0,0)
    white = (255,255,255)
    surf = pygame.Surface(font.size(text))
    surf.fill(white)
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black, surf)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()
```

Comment: I changed my code from background.blit(textSurf, textRect) to screen.blit(textSurf, textRect). The text can display on the button now, but it is flashing there. I want it to be static.

Comment: You need to provide more code. You have no reference of screen in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem. I should change the code `background.blit(textSurf, textRect)` to `screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)`. After this change, the text can display on the button, however, the text is flashing, in order to solve this problem, I added a Clock function there to control the frequency of updating. And the final code are here:

```
ButtonText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 10)
textSurf, textRect = text_objects("Mute", ButtonText)
textRect.center = ((20+(50/2)), (20+(20/2)) )

screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)     
pygame.display.flip()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
clock.tick(15)
```